# What would prevent me from re-creating a missing /dev/null folder?

Tags: macos, mac, unix

I noticed on my home machine (OS X 10.6.6) that somehow the `/dev/null` folder got corrupted. It seemed to exist when browsing in Finder or Terminal, but wouldn't accept any output written to it, and I couldn't CHMOD it, etc. It seemed to be either dead or corrupted!

So I deleted it, and undertook the standard fix:

```
# rm /dev/null
# mknod /dev/null c 1 3
# chmod 666 /dev/null
# ls -l /dev/null
```

But, when I try typing `mknod /dev/null c 1 3` I get an error message:

```
Illegal instruction
```

It's definitely gone - so I don't think I'm illegally trying to create the same folder.

I've tried looking for another combination - for example: mknod /dev/null c 2 2, etc - but nothing works.

What should I do?

Comment: `/dev/null` isn't a "folder" (or directory), it's a special file.

Comment: Did you make sure that you only have `mknod` in `/sbin` and not elsewhere earlier in your `PATH`? (check with `type -a mknod` in bash)

Answer (score 2):

On my system, it's `3, 2`.

```
$ ls -l /dev/null
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel    3,   2 28 Jan 19:01 /dev/null
```

Comment: I still get "Illegal Instruction" when I try: 'sudo mknod /dev/null c 3 2'

Comment: @Jamison what about `sudo mknod null c 3 2`? The `man mknod` examples don't specify the whole path.

Comment: ahh! That's good thinking! - they just specify "name" as a parameter. Shucks - I just tried it, and got the same Illegal Instruction message

Comment: Here's something strange: in FINDER, there is a symlink to DEV, but if I try to follow it I get a "Dev can’t be opened because the original item can’t be found." symlink error.  But in Terminal, cd dev takes me right there and I can browse the contents normally with ls, etc. I'm not sure where the DEV folder is located now...

Comment: @Jamison `/dev` doesn't open for me in Finder, too. Neither *Go to Folder* (which fails with "not found"), nor `open /dev` in Terminal.

Comment: yeah - I'm thinking now that the mknod system folders aren't accessible via Finder - nor can I locate the contents of the folder with the terminal "locate" command

Comment: Jamison That's not the issue right now, is it? :-) I just did the following: `sudo mknod /dev/null2 c 3 2` and got `crw-r--r--   1 root        wheel       3,   2 28 Jan 19:32 null2` in `ls -al /dev | grep null`. The original is `crw-rw-rw-   1 root        wheel       3,   2 28 Jan 19:01 null`. Seems to work for me.

Comment: yes - exactly! By all indications it should work - I just tried creating another folder "null2" like your example, and still get the "Illegal instruction" message.  Now I'm investigating that message, specifically...

Comment: @Jamison Doesn't help that this topic is the first Google hit. Did you try to restart? Anyway, good luck.

Comment: I'll restart in a few minutes- I'm worried that if there's a file system error, it will restart badly. This is weird - I looked at the data for another common DEV (mknod) folder - 'zero' and got this: $ ls -al /dev | grep zero
crw-rw-rw-   1 root     wheel           3,   3 Jan 20 11:29 zero // // so I just tried again with 'c 3 3' as the numeration on the command and it gave me the same error

Comment: `/dev` appears to be a special filesystem (union of `devfs` and `fdesc`), at least on my computer (V10.5.8). Maybe that's the explanation.

Answer (score 2):

The same problem here on Mac OS X 10.6.8 after testing the GNU `script` command using `/dev/null` as log file in a wrong way:

```
# wrong use of GNU script command (do not use it!)
#sudo sh -c '
#0<&- gscript -q /dev/null -c "x11vnc -storepasswd ~/.vnc/passwd << EOF
#password
#password
#y
#EOF"
#sync
#'


sudo ls -ld /
# Illegal instruction

ls -l /dev/null
# crw-------  1 root  wheel    3,   2 31 Jan 15:31 /dev/null
```

The solution that worked for me was to shut down the computer (by holding down the power button), restart it into single user mode (with cmd and s keys pressed) and then (twice) **repeat** `/sbin/fsck -fy` until the message appeared: `** The volume (name_of_volume) appears to be OK` (see: [Resolve startup issues and perform disk maintenance with Disk Utility and fsck](http://support.apple.com/kb/ts1417)).

Comment: On Mac OS X 10.6.8 I lost `/dev/null` after a 'port install' with the symptoms described by the OP. Just [restarting into single user mode](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH6825) and then rebooting `shutdown -r now` (without doing any filesystem repairs) fixed the issue. (See also [/dev/null permissions causing "Illegal instruction"](http://www.dslreports.com/forum/r26044139-OS-X-dev-null-permissions-causing-qIllegal-instruction-q) for this exact solution.)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, all comments and solutions (above) were correct - in the end, the filesystem was corrupted like I suspected.

The solution was to boot up with the INSTALL/BOOT disk, and run Disk Utility. Inside Disk Utility, I simply had to select my Hard Disk (they're listed by name), and then click the "Repair Disk" button - it scanned for a good 1.5 hours, and fixed all the errors, including restoring my Dev/Null folder.

I saw a lot of different instructions in online forums about how to boot up directly into Disk Utility - including "insert boot disk into drive, turn computer off, when re-booting, hold down the "C" key, and you will enter Disk Utility!"

ACTUALLY - that didn't work for my OS X 10.6.6 - I instead had to boot up with my boot disk, enter the OS X Install screens, and you can find the "Disk Utility" program in the "Utilities" menu.

Here are the steps- this works for any/all maintenance you want to do on your OS X 10.6.6 Filesystem:

NOTE: these are only instructions to repair your MAIN HARD DISK that you usually use to boot up. You can't repair this disk when you're running OS X, so you'll need to re-boot into your BootUp Disk to do the repairs. To repair any/all other disks, you can simply go to UTILITIES>Disk Utility, select the disk you want to repair, and click the "Repair" button.

TO FIX MAIN HARD-DISK (main boot up disk):

1. Insert your OS X Disk into the computer (it could be your original OS X CD, or a USB key loaded with a copy of a OS X INSTALL disk.)
2. Turn computer off.
3. Restart computer while holding down ALT/OPTION key during boot-up, keep holding it until you see a screen that lists the different "boot" hard disks and/or USB keys currently plugged in to your system. In my case, I saw my installed Hard Disk (the old one I want to fix) and my OS X CD, which the system recognizes as a boot disk too.
4. Click on the CD (or USB key).
5. It will take 30secs to a minute, but your OS X Install screens will open up - click on the language you want (English in my case) and click continue.
6. BE CAREFUL - in the next few screens, you don't want to click on "Install" or anything similar -you should now see a new MENU BAR along the top of your screen, with a menu called "Utilities".
   7.Click on "Utilities" and select "Disk Utility".
7. Now you're inside the Disk Utility program - simply select the Hard Disk you want to repair, and then click on the "REPAIR" button. It'll take an hour or two to scan and fix everything, but it should work!

When that finishes, click to CLOSE the Disk Utility program. I couldn't find any way to restart the computer, so I just held down the power button, and then again to re-start. Don't press anything and the computer should reboot into your main OS X install (hard disk) with no problems.

Thanks -

Comment: It's not a folder